# Installed everything but still get unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python

I have Python 3.4 64-bit installed
I have installed Visual Studio 2015
I have installed gcc for windows
I have installed gcc-mingw
I have installed mingw-w64

No matter what I do I cannot get to fix this error

unable to find vcvarsall.bat

I also cannot find the file on my system doing a normal search. So what else can I do to make this work please?

Comment: presumably you've checked all the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?rq=1

Comment: The vc vars are usually in the Microsoft Visual Studio Common7 Tools folder. Which may not be on your path. What is giving you this error and why is the tagged python?

Comment: And note from the linked answer by @EdChum they talked about a different VS to the one you mention.

Comment: Where is `vcvarsall.bat` on your machine? What is the value of `path` in your command prompt? Is the directory containing `vcvarsall.bat` also in `path`?